# Chat through serial port

Tags: ethernet

I have completed software part but need help in hardware side. We are given few components and asked to do communication (chat) between two PCs.

Components list is:

1. USB to TTL converter
2. Ethernet cable
3. 75176 I.C

We have to use one 75176 IC to communicate 2 PCs users. If someone has done this so please help how to make these components work.

Comment: Datasheet for [SN75176A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75176a.pdf). Please provide a part# and/or data for the USB to TTL converter. Are you allowed any other components? I assume you mean one 75176 per PC?

Comment: You get better help here if you show off what you have already done / thought about and then ask a specific question about a  specific problem.

Comment: You realize that you have a half-duplex transceiver, right?

Comment: With proper software a half-duplex system could work - it might just be noticibly slower if the baud rate is low.

Comment: Plug ethernet cable in at both ends.  Set IP addresses.  Open netcat on both PCs.  Ignore IC and usb ttl adapter :)  Problem solved! Unless you are using ancient PCs, they have onboard network cards.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: PC ↔ USB-TTL ↔ 75176 ↔ Ethernet cable ↔ 75176 ↔ TTL-USB ↔ PC